idx.google.com consume endPoint
I have a small problem and it is that I cannot find a way to consume an endpoint that I created with Java and SpringBoot on https://idx.google.com/. Something like pointing to a localhost:8080/{endPoint}. Is there any specific configuration to do this?
Probe algo como:
curl --location 'https://idx.google.com/get-weather-610861/saludar' \
--header 'accept: application/json'

pero nada.
Este seria el endPoint::
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

  @Value("${NAME:World}")
  String name;

  @RestController
  class HelloworldController {
    @GetMapping("/saludar")
    String hello() {
      return "Hello " + name + "!";
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }

}


There is option in sidebar of idx with idx logo where you can see url and host in which your port is exposed.

I found it. Thank you very much.
